# problem with imagecreatefromstring function

Tags: php, image

I am trying to convert a string to an image using the "**`imagecreatefromstring`**" function
(I've attached the code below). It works for most images, but when I try to convert
larger images, a small portion of the image does not get converted (the lower part
of the image is just grey)

my code is (take it from php.net example) :

```
            $data = base64_decode($record['text']);

            $im = imagecreatefromstring($data);
            if ($im !== false) {
                header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
                imagejpeg($im);
                imagedestroy($im);
            }
```

i also try different way to decode the string not in one pice , but splitting the string and then decode it.

```
 for($i=0, $len=strlen($record['text']); $i<$len; $i+=4){
                $data.= base64_decode( substr($record['text'], $i, 4) );
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like your data has been truncated, either on storage or on retrieval. Verify that you have the entire image in your store.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to base64 decode the string, that's probably the root of your problem.

Comment: i need it i think , if i drop it is print error :
Data is not in a recognized format

Comment: @haim evgi: Aren't you also base64 **encoding** the data in the first place?

Comment: i edit the question , i decode only one time (one time or by split)